# Create library from single / multiple existing files within git repo?

Tags: git, github

I have a private git repo for a project.

In there, a few file exist which I'd like to make available as a separate library, as they're not application specific and can be reused.

Is there a way to fork a git repo so that it contains just these few files, retaining the version history but ignoring all other files?

The other files need to be kept private, so I can't simply fork the whole repo and remove them for future commits.

Answer (score 0):

> In there, a few file exist which I'd like to make available as a separate library

**You should submodules.**

[image]

Submodules is a **independent** project inside another project, which is self managed in its own folder.

In your case since you already have the code inside a big one repository so you will have to break it down to small pieces.

---

> so I can't simply fork the whole repo and remove them for future commits.

To do it use this tool [bfc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34836866/split-git-repository-in-different-repositories-to-reduce-size/34840842#34840842).
In your case simply clean out the `subfolders` which you are changing to be `submodules`, and you remove them completely from your history.

[image]

---

## Important note:

Following the above steps will perform a rebase on your branch, so you will have to know the consequences of a rebase which will force everyone with this branch to drop it and clone it again after your changes.